# Disable eslint for specific namespace

Tags: javascript, eslint

In my code I am using opencv.js and it has some methods which do not follow my eslint rules, for example:

```js
/* globals cv */
...
cv.GaussianBlur(...);
...
...
```

The above line will give the "new-cap" eslint error (A function with a name starting with an uppercase letter should only be used as a constructor).

Can I configure eslint to ignore anything related to `cv` ?
Thx.